# Double letters in Esperanto

Tags: spelling

When I started to learn Esperanto, I remember that one said to me there are no exceptions and the words sound how they are written. 
So I'm really surprised to see some words with double letters such as *Pollando* or *Finnlando* (I guess there are not the only words with double letters).

So, why those words have double letters? Is it not possible to write *Polando* or *Finlando*? Is it an exception (so it is in conflict with my first assertion)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These words don’t break the rule because they really are supposed to be pronounced differently by lingering on the consonant a little longer. Usually the double consonants come about because of two roots being combined, such as *Pollando* which is the *lando* of *poloj*. *Finno* on the other hand is one of the rare roots that contains a double consonant. If it was just written like *fino* there would likely be confusion with the word for “end”, so *finlando* could be a country at the end of the world or something.

Take a look at Forvo for the difference in pronunciation between [*fino*](https://forvo.com/search/fino/eo/) and [*finnlando*](https://forvo.com/word/finnlando/#eo).

PMEG has [a long description](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/elparolo/specialaj_reguloj.html#i-c9j) of this.

Answer (score 5):

*Pollando* is only a double letter due to a morpheme boundary: /pol-land-o/ ("Land of the Poles"). So one should probably pronounce the two /l/s as separate letters.

According to my (1977) copy of JC Wells' "Esperanto Dictionary", Finland is *Finlando*, so all normal there.

**Update:** The *Finnlando* issue seems to have been changed, ie it is indeed a double consonant. As Neil mentions in his answer, *finn-* is a double consonant root, because *fin-* was already taken. This is a general problem when (constructed) languages meet reality (ie names), that they often don't really fit into the phonological or morphological structure of a language. You can either sacrifice consistency (as in allowing a double consonant root), or you have to pick a different name (which then nobody will recognise as easily). It seems Esperanto has developed along the former line.

Comment: Hm, according to _my_ copy of JC Wells’ dictionary Finland is _Finnlando_ 

Comment: It's inconsistent: EO "Finlando" is "Finland", but EN "Finland" is "Finnlando"!

Comment: In my 2010 edition it isn’t inconsistent, it is _Finnlando_ in both directions…

Comment: Mine is from 1977 ;) -- but yes, it makes sense to avoid the conflict with _fin-_

Comment: I’ve seen *Suomio* used as an alternative Esperanto name for Finland (from Finnish *Suomi*). Of course, few non-Finns would recognise the root. Then again, Esperantists somehow got used to *Barato* for India and *Kimrio* for Wales…

Comment: I tend to think of the country as Suomio, when in Esperanto context. Maybe in time this usage will solidify.

Comment: It's quite obvious once you worked out why their international code (on cars) is SF...